# unlist a list of scala.xml.Elem to a single scala.xml.Elem

Tags: scala

say I have a List of scala.xml.Elem such as

```
val xmls = List(<div id = "tab1" class="tabcontent"> tab1_content_here </div>, 
     <div id = "tab2" class="tabcontent"> tab2_content_here </div>)
```

I need to be able to "unlist" this list of xml.Elem into one xml.Elem such as

```
scala.xml.Elem = <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent"> tab1_content_here </div>
                 <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent"> tab2_content_here </div>
```

I am trying to build a set of different tabcontents simialr to what is displayed on this page https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

I tried converting the list to string and use
`scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmls.mkString(""))`

I get a `org.xml.sax.SAXParserException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed`

Okay, thats cool, so its something to do with XML formatting I think? I tried to make the format similar to what the example page has by calling
`scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmls.mkString("\n\n"))`

I get the same error, further search led me to this post [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285103/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-elem) so it looks like I can't have

```
<div id="tab1"></div>
<div id="tab2"></div>
```

But then why does the w3 example contains exactly that and managed to parse that XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an XML document can only have a single top-level element, so you can't "unlist" to valid XML. You can, however, wrap the list in an outer element:

```
<wrapper>{xmls}</wrapper>
```

which gives

```
<wrapper>
  <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent"> tab1_content_here </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent"> tab2_content_here </div>
</wrapper>
```